# How to comparate MULTILINESTRING geometry type with POINT geometry type in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, postgis

I want to comparate `MULTILINESTRING` geometry type with `POINT` geometry type.
In order to test if an (XY) from MULTILINESTRING match with an (XY) from POINT.
Basically `MULTILINESTRING` type look like something like that : `MULTILINESTRING((918844.55 6670885.31,918778.87 6670898.9, 918502.96 6670936.35))`, the number of (XY) coordinates can be more than 3.
And `POINT` type look like this : `POINT(920892.39 6671627.92)`, but the number of (XY) coordinates  is the same.

I get this data from postgreSQl database and I don't any problem to retrieve them nor to parse each geometry type but it's to comparate them.

The difficulty I encounter is when I get `MULTILINESTRING` geometry type I retrieve a dataset where each lines are like the example above. So I need to comparate each (XY) coordinate of `MULTILINESTRING` geometry type to each (XY) `POINT` geometry type. If the value match I want to `INSERT`the (XY) coordinates to a table.

Below my code and explanations :

```vb
Sub importcb_smn(ByVal myConnection As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection)

        Dim infoDataset As DataSet, infoDataset2 As DataSet
'Here I get MULTILINESTRING type
        infoDataset = accessRequet_odbc("select st_astext(st_snaptogrid(geom, 0.01)) from netgeo_cable", myConnection)
'Here I get POINT type
        infoDataset2 = accessRequet_odbc("select st_astext(st_snaptogrid(geom, 0.01)) from netgeo_point_tech", myConnection)


        Dim t1 As Long = infoDataset2.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        Dim t2 As Long
        Dim geomCable As String, geomPt(t1) As String, geomSplit(t2) As String
        Dim parse1 As String, parse2 As String, parse3 As String
'Here I parse POINT type data to dump it into an array
        For i = 0 To infoDataset2.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            parse1 = infoDataset2.Tables(0).Rows(i).ItemArray(0).Remove(0, 6)
            geomPt(i) = parse1.Substring(0, parse1.Length - 1)
        Next
'Here I parse MULTILINESTRING type
        For i = 0 To infoDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            parse2 = infoDataset.Tables(0).Rows(i).ItemArray(0).Remove(0, 17)
            geomCable = parse2.Substring(0, parse2.Length - 2)
            geomSplit = Split(geomCable, ",")
'I test if value matches 
            For j = 0 To UBound(geomPt)
                If geomPt(j) = geomSplit(i) Then
                    Call executeCommand("insert into netgeo_cable_bis(geom) values (st_geometryfromtext('POINT(" & geomSplit(i) & ")',2154))", myConnection)
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```

So I try to comparate 2 array. First I parse and dump each line of `infoDataset2` into `geomPt()`. So each line of `geomPt()` is (XY) string.

Then I parse and dump one line of `infoDataset` into `geomSplit()`. But here each line of `geomSplit()` is just (XY) coordinates of 1 line of `infoDaset`.

That's why I try to comparate whithin the same loop. To test every (XY) coordinates of every lines of `infoDataset` with each lines of `infoDataset2`.

I get an error at `if geomPt(j) = geomSplit(i) then` saying : `System.IndexOutOfRangeException : The index is outside the limits of the table`. But I don't see how to fix it.

I want to learn from this, so, if possible, explain to me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Comment: have a look at [`st_dumpPoints()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html). You could do the point to vertex comparison in a single query directly in the DB

Comment: @JGH I'm using st_dumppoints() as you suggested. Now I can find exactly each point of my linestring that are close to a point. Furthermore I can get float position of points on the linestring. I just want to insert the new linestring but my query is failling : `insert into netgeo_cable_cut(geom, id_pt, id_cable_origin) values (ST_Line_Substring(SELECT geom FROM netgeo_cable_test WHERE id = id_cable_origin,0,0.259661215386615),8218, 7);
`. The error says : `error syntax near or on SELECT` . (Second SELECT). Do you have any idea how can I get this fixed ?

Comment: you can add another parenthesis around the inner `select .. from .. where` statement

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JGH who suggested me to try whith a `Postgis` function to do the comparison. Indeed it is better to let the database do that work because it is made for that.

So first I do a `SELECT` query to get all the points of my cables (with `st_dumppoints()` that are near a point of comparison (`st_dwithin()`). Then I get index position of each point on the cable to build a new linestring (with `st_line_locate_point()`).

In VB.NET my query look like this : `infoDataset = accessRequet_odbc("SELECT req.id, (dp).geom, netgeo_point_tech.id, ST_Line_Locate_Point(ST_LineMerge(geom_cable), (dp).geom)
FROM (SELECT id, ST_DumpPoints(geom) as dp, geom as geom_cable FROM netgeo_cable_test) as req
LEFT JOIN netgeo_point_tech ON ST_dwithin(netgeo_point_tech.geom, (dp).geom, 1) 
ORDER BY req.id, (dp).path [ 1] ASC", myConnection)`

Then I need to parse the result I get to extract index position and origin cable id.
With the id of original cable and the float (index position) I can insert a new `linsestring` which is a part of the original cable.

Let me know guys if my explanations make sense.